# Ionic streaming media plugin issue

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm trying to build an ionic app to stream audio feeds.

Here's what I have so far...

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { StreamingMedia } from '@ionic-native/streaming-media';

import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    StreamingMedia,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

home.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StreamingMedia, StreamingAudioOptions } from '@ionic-native/streaming-media';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private streamingMedia: StreamingMedia) {

  }

    playStream() {

        let options: StreamingAudioOptions = {
            bgColor: 'red',
            successCallback: () => { console.log('Audio played') },
            errorCallback: (e) => { console.log('Error streaming') }
        };

        this.streamingMedia.playAudio('http://listen.radionomy.com:80/NewYorkClassicRock');

    }

}
```

home.html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      Ionic Blank
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  The world is your oyster.
  <p>
    If you get lost, the <a href="http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2">docs</a> will be your guide.
  </p>

  <button ion-button large (click)="playStream()">Start the Stream!</button>
</ion-content>
```

Using ionic view, clicking the button does nothing in android or ios.

What am I doing wrong or missing?

Thanks!

Comment: _Using ionic view_.. plugins dont work with `ionic serve` as cordova is not loaded..you have to use device/emulator.. also call plugins within [plaform.ready](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/platform/Platform/#ready)

Comment: I used the same code. works fine for me. Thought the audio streaming link is wrong but it works perfectly fine for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will not work in ionic view.
Run it on a physical device using the command:

cordova run android --debug

from within your app folder !

Answer (score 1):

One small observation, you are setting the options but not passing it to the `streamingMedia`. You might want to do this:

```js
this.streamingMedia.playAudio('http://listen.radionomy.com:80/NewYorkClassicRock',options);
```